Is it possible to create file with an HTTP request using sharing link?
I have a link like https://Site.com/:f:/g/EZbyBEYvwBGolyOlTcIFCsBMHvkZVhxKmH41o4D0egmg and need to put a file there, but it looks like SharePoint REST API endpoints want only server-related path. And I can't manage to access the sharing link using GET request via API at all
